# Custom font doesn't work after localization

Tags: ios, fonts, localization, storyboard

I'm using a custom font for English version of my app, before localizing for other languages, the font displayed fine, then I localized the app for Chinese, the custom font is replaced by system font when I run it, though it still looks right on the storyboard.

I set the font in storyboard, I think it's a easier approach as I have multiple view controllers using this font in different places, it'd be a little complicated to set font with code, here's the storyboard setting:

[image]

and info.plist:

[image]

localization:

[image]

So, what's wrong?

Comment: Before localisation which Xcode you have used? and After localisation which Xcode are you using? I mean Xcode versions.

Comment: @YogeshMv Xcode 8.1 before, 8.2 after

Comment: Because I faced this issue in Xcode 8.0. After I migrated to Xcode 8.1 it is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by disabling localization of the font like this:

[image]